# How get string name of the model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Some Laravel plugins keep referencing models like this:

```
App\Vote
```

when the model is defined as app/Vote.php :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use DB;
use App\MyAppModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class Vote extends MyAppModel
{
    use funcsTrait;
    use Sluggable;
    use HasTags;


    protected $table = 'votes';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

I am wondering how to get the "App\Vote" string from this model?

Laravel 5.7.

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you want to get the name? Do you have an instance of this model?

Comment: in Control. I can use with(new Vote)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the [fully qualified class name](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) like this:

```
\App\Vote::class;
```

or

```
use App\Vote;

Vote::class;
```